# Web API Complex Object on a Get method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, get, deserialization, query-string, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple complex object that WebAPI V2 is not completely deserializing as expected. I am using the [FromUri] attribute to make sure that the model is deserialized from the URI and as you can see below the serialization that takes place works, but is incomplete.

*I have removed comments and empty parameter constructors for brevity*

The Models

```
public class ClientSuggestRequestModel
{
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public List<string> Fields { get; set; }
    public List<SearchTerm> SearchTerms { get; set; }
}

public class SearchTerm
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
}
```

The WebAPI V2 Controller action:

```
public IEnumerable<SuggestionModel> GetSuggestResults([FromUri]string resourceType, [FromUri]ClientSuggestRequestModel requestData)
{
    /* body removed for brevity */
}
```

The request being made is correct as the Angular serializer is functioning as expected.

```
http://localhost/api/SearchSuggest/asset/Feline?fields=FIELD.TITLE&fields=FIELD.ASSET_TYPE&limit=5&searchTerms=%7B%22Field%22%3A%22FIELD.TITLE%22%2C%22Term%22%3A%22Cats%22%7D&searchTerms=%7B%22Field%22%3A%22FIELD.ASSET_TYPE%22%2C%22Term%22%3A%22Poster%22%7D
```

The WebAPI V2 Action Results in a serialized model as such:

ACTUAL:

```
{
    SearchText: "Feline",
    Limit: 5,
    Fields: [
        "FIELD.TITLE",
        "FIELD.ASSET_TYPE"
    ],
    SearchTerms: [
        {
            Field: null,
            Term: null
        },
        {
            Field: null,
            Term: null
        },
    ]
}
```

EXPECTED:

```
{
    SearchText: "Feline",
    Limit: 5,
    Fields: [
        "FIELD.TITLE",
        "FIELD.ASSET_TYPE"
    ],
    SearchTerms: [
        {
            Field: "FIELD.TITLE",
            Term: "Cats"
        },
        {
            Field: "FIELD.ASSET_TYPE",
            Term: "Poster"
        },
    ]
}
```

QUESTION: What do I need to do to make sure that the 'SearchTerm' model is populated with the values? It obviously knew that the fields where there and created an array to the expected length. The values of each object are null and not the expected.

Comment: I would check the media formatter in the WebApiConfig.cs file to make sure it is using the json formatter.  Side question is there a reason you are not implementing this as a post?

Comment: my WebApiConfig does use the JsonFormatter since I am applying the camelCase formatter so that my JSON adheres to 'our' (the companies) JavaScript Coding Practice.

Comment: As for your side question. This is a GET request because we are requesting data from a RESTful service, it just happens that our query string supports a complex syntax for modifying the REQUEST. A POST is for sending data that will be stored into a SERVER Repository. This is a primary rule for RESTful development.